# Applying pre-production modifications

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, wpdb, migration, subscription

I'm working on a wordpress website on a pre-production version that includes several extensions like woocommerce and others. I'm wondering what is a safe solution to apply all the modifications I made on the production website without risking to lose user informations...

I think the safest way is to import the user and their orders, subscriptions (...) on the preprod version and once it's good, copy the whole thing to the production one, but how to be sure what mysql tables I have to import ?

For example orders are in part in wp_posts, but I can have added some page there will have order posts with the same ID as some page posts.

Comment: do you want to sync pre-production site and production site after you have made changes to pre-production site?

Comment: Yes if sync means only one time.

Comment: An idea on how to do ?